# Store or reflect on the "reference level" of a variable

Tags: c++, variables

Is there a way in C++ to reflect on the "number of levels of pointer" of a variable, (for example, `int* a` is 1 level, `int** b` is 2 levels, and `int c` is 0 levels)

..Other than using `typeid` and parsing the string that comes out of that?

The reason I'm asking is I am using [pointers to member functions](http://www.goingware.com/tips/member-pointers.html), and I need to know whether to invoke the member function as `obj->func()` or `obj.func()`, at compile time really.

Comment: You mean (obj->*func)() vs (obj.*func)(), since func is a ptmf.  Why don't you "know" whether obj is a pointer or not?  How did you get obj?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `std::is_pointer` from the `type_traits` header in TR1 (which uses partial specialization to produce an answer), but it might be simpler to just use overload resolution.

Here's an example, assuming void return, no arguments, and no need to handle more than one level of indirection:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
inline void invoke(T& obj, F func)
{
    (obj.*func)();
}

template <typename T, typename F>
inline void invoke(T* obj, F func)
{
    (obj->*func)();
}
```

If you need to handle more than one level of indirection, you can replace the second function with this:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
inline void invoke(T* obj, F func)
{
    invoke(*obj, func);
}
```

This will recursively strip off levels of indirection until you end up with something that you can invoke your member function on.

Answer (score 4):

If `obj` is a `T**`, doing `obj.*foo` is ill-formed. So you only need to figure out whether it is a pointer or a non-pointer. You can use overloading for this.

```
template<typename T, typename M> void f(T *obj, M m) { // pointer
  (obj->*m)();
}

template<typename T, typename M> void f(T &obj, M m) { // not a pointer
  (obj.*m)();
}
```

This has the drawback that it only works with zero-parameter member function pointers, and it won't return the value (if any) that those functions return. You cannot do the following (which can easily be implemented), because both branches will be type-checked

```
if(is_pointer(obj)) v = (obj->*m)(arg...); else v = (obj.*m)(args...);
```

What you *can* do is to just call a function to dereference your object, if it is a pointer

```
template<typename T> T &deref(T *t) { return *t; }
template<typename T> T &deref(T &t) { return t; }
```

Then you can say

```
v = (deref(obj).*m)(args...);
```

Comment: You also need to differentiate `T*` from `T**`, because `obj->*foo` works for the former and not the latter.

Comment: @Ben that's my point. You don't need to care about `T**`, because it works with neither `.*` nor with `->*`. It's an error to call `f` with such a pointer.

Comment: @Johannes: `T` works with `(obj).*foo`, `T*` works with `(*obj).*foo` (or `->*`), `T**` works with `(**obj).*foo`, usw

Comment: @Ben that's true. But that's a different issue. The issue was to detect when to use `.*` and when `->*`, and the questioner started to think about a solution too general for this, which alone isn't even able to solve this (both branches will be type-checked, see above). As explained by @John for the first approach (zero-args, no-return), if you do `return deref(*t);` in the pointer case, the shown solution can easily be generalized to handle arbitrary pointer-nesting. Unless that is needed, I would keep it without, because then you detect more caller-bugs and hide less.

Comment: @Johannes: If you do `T &deref(T *t) { return deref(*t); }` you will handle arbitrary pointer level.

Comment: I don't see the point of this as the compiler will generate a compile time error if the wrong type of object is used. I suppose this could be useful if you were writing a template function and wanted to handle arbitrator deep nested pointers that you can not determine the depth of at the point of writing. But; I suspect that the OP is not at that point and thus this is overkill for his situation.

Comment: See more details on the context [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238547/reference-level-part-2)

Comment: OK. Based on the next question. This is exactly what he needs.

Answer (score 3):

Partial template specialization will tell you quite easily:

```
template<typename T>
struct PtrLevel
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template<typename TTarget>
struct PtrLevel<TTarget*>
{
    enum { value = PtrLevel<TTarget>::value + 1 };
};
```

Demonstration: http://ideone.com/ZPH8X

In C++0x, you could probably use `decltype` and SFINAE to handle smart pointers in such a way that they are reported as having a non-zero pointer level.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of template magic to the rescue:

```
template<typename T>
struct Depth { enum DepthEnum { value = 0 };};

template<typename T>
struct Depth<T*> { enum DepthEnum{ value = Depth<T>::value +1 };};

template<typename T>
size_t getDepth(T const& o)
{
    return Depth<T>::value;
}

int main()
{
    int         a0;
    int*        a1;
    int**       a2;
    int***      a3;
    int****     a4;
    int*****    a5;
    int******   a6;
    std::cout << getDepth(a0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getDepth(a1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getDepth(a2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getDepth(a3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getDepth(a4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getDepth(a5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << getDepth(a6) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
> g++ test.cpp
> ./a.out
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Going back to the reason you want it. That seems a bit suspect. Your compiler already knows what version to sue at compile time. Remember C++ is very strict on its typing and this information is known at compile time thus if you use the wrong version you will get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any built in way to do this, but you could implement a small template class that simulates a "counting pointer" in the sense that you can easily determine your "pointer depth" like this:

```
template <typename T> class Ptr {
  private:
    T* ptr;
    int d;
  public:
    // overload all meaningful operators, like * etc.
    // e.g.
    T& operator*() {
      return *T;
    }
    int depth() const {
      return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Templates are right, but creating your own smart pointer is not.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: It's not a smart pointer. It is merely a layer of indirection to store additional information for the pointer.

Comment: That's what a smart pointer is: a class wrapping a pointer and providing additional behavior.

Answer (score 0):

as long as your pointer is valid you can use the following code: it'll give you refrence level to the object you pass to it (and just by a little change you can change it to return the object pointers refer to, just use comments instead of acual code and directly use countPartial):

```
template <class T> int countPartial(T *x,int depth)
//use template <class T> T& countPartial(T *x)
{
    return countPartial(*x,depth+1);
    //return countPartial(*x);
}

template <class T> int countPartial(T &x,int depth)
//use template <class T> T& countPartial(T &x)
{
    return depth;
    //return x;
}

template <class T> int count(T x)

{
    return countPartial(x,0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

probably this shud solve ur trouble
T is template.
funcptr the ptr to function.

```
int callfunc( T ptr)
{

depth = 0;

if ( typeof(ptr)!=  typeof(funcptr))

{


depth++;
depth = depth + callfunc(*ptr);
}
return depth;
}
```