# Reference level part 2

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

[Expanding on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238216/store-or-reflect-on-the-reference-level-of-a-variable), it looks like I did not provide enough detail.

I have an object called `CallbackObject` that is designed to contain an object instance, and the information of what function to invoke, and the parameters to pass at invokation time.

```
template <typename objectType,
          typename memberFunctionPtrType,
          typename memberFcnArg1Type>
struct CallbackObject1
{
  objectType obj ;
  memberFunctionPtrType fcnPtr ;
  memberFcnArg1Type arg1 ;

  CallbackObject1(objectType iObj,
                  memberFunctionPtrType iFcnPtr,
                  memberFcnArg1Type iArg1 )
  {
    obj = iObj ;
    fcnPtr = iFcnPtr ;
    arg1 = iArg1 ;
  }

  void exec()
  {
    (obj.*fcnPtr)( arg1 ) ;
  }
} ;
```

#### Example of use:

```
struct Point
{
  float x,y ;
  void print( int numTimes )
  {
    for( int i = 0 ; i < numTimes ; i++ )
      printf( "%f %f\n", x, y ) ;
  }
} ;

typedef void (Point::* PointPrintFcnType)( int ) ;

int main()
{
  Point p ;
  p.x=p.y=1;

  CallbackObject1<Point, PointPrintFcnType, int> ocall( p, &Point::print, 5 );
  ocall.exec() ;
}
```

The only problem I'm having is if `objectType` is a pointer type, then `(obj.*fcnPtr)` fails, since it should really read `( (*obj).*fcnPtr)` or `(obj->*fcnPtr)` if obj is a pointer.

Now I have one solution, where I define **another** CallbackObject class like so:

```
template <typename pObjectType,
          typename memberFunctionPtrType,
          typename memberFcnArg1Type>
struct CallbackPObject1
{
  pObjectType obj ;
  memberFunctionPtrType fcnPtr ;
  memberFcnArg1Type arg1 ;

  CallbackPObject1(pObjectType iObj,
                  memberFunctionPtrType iFcnPtr,
                  memberFcnArg1Type iArg1 )
  {
    obj = iObj ;
    fcnPtr = iFcnPtr ;
    arg1 = iArg1 ;
  }

  void exec()
  {
    (obj->*fcnPtr)( arg1 ) ;
  }
} ;
```

But this is crufty at best, and difficult to use at worst, if someone else is using this code, they will have to create a different kind of Callback object if the object type being used is actually a pointer.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Any of the answers provided in your first question would've worked, including partial specialization (your second class could've been a partial specialization of the first) and using an overloaded function as a helper function to actually perform the call.

Comment: How will they work for a class?

Comment: Exactly the same way. Your problem is that it's difficult to write the expression in `exec()`. If you use Johannes' or my answer, it provides a helper function that you can use to write that statement in `exec()` generically. Said helper functions could just be global functions or private member functions.

Comment: Yeah, it is difficult to write exec().  I copped out with an if statement, see my answer below.  How else could you write exec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example helper function, assuming void return, one argument, and no need to handle more than one level of indirection:

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename A>
inline void invoke(T& obj, F func, const A& arg)
{
    (obj.*func)(arg);
}

template <typename T, typename F, typename A>
inline void invoke(T* obj, F func, const A& arg)
{
    (obj->*func)(arg);
}
```

If you need to handle more than one level of indirection, you can replace the second function with this:

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename A>
inline void invoke(T* obj, F func, const A& arg)
{
    invoke(*obj, func, arg);
}
```

This will recursively strip off levels of indirection until you end up with something that you can invoke your member function on.

You can then write your `exec()` function like so:

```
void exec()
{
    invoke(obj, fcnPtr, arg1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a polymorphic function object such as `boost::function` in combination with functor-producing functions like `boost::bind`. These are a far superior solution- the genius happens when the functor is produced, not when it's called, and any function object that can be called with the correct signature may be called.

Comment: Also I did try out `boost::bind` and its cool but I want to do it this way.  Sorry if this sounds ocd, but I don't want to use boost::function for solving this particular problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, applying the "overload" approach on the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238216/store-or-reflect-on-the-reference-level-of-a-variable) I get

```
template <typename objectType,
          typename memberFunctionPtrType,
          typename memberFcnArg1Type>
struct CallbackObject1 : public Callback
{
  objectType obj ;
  objectType *pObj ;
  memberFunctionPtrType fcnPtr ;
  memberFcnArg1Type arg1 ;

  CallbackObject1(objectType iObj,
                  memberFunctionPtrType iFcnPtr,
                  memberFcnArg1Type iArg1 )
  {
    obj = iObj ;
    pObj = 0 ;
    fcnPtr = iFcnPtr ;
    arg1 = iArg1 ;
  }

  CallbackObject1(objectType *iObj,
                  memberFunctionPtrType iFcnPtr,
                  memberFcnArg1Type iArg1 )
  {
    pObj = iObj ;
    fcnPtr = iFcnPtr ;
    arg1 = iArg1 ;
  }

  void exec()
  {
    if( pObj )
      (pObj->*fcnPtr)( arg1 ) ;
    else
      (obj.*fcnPtr)( arg1 ) ;
  }
} ;
```

#### Use

```
  typedef void (Point::* PointPrintFcnType)( int ) ;

  Point p ;
  p.x=p.y=1;

  CallbackObject1<Point, PointPrintFcnType, int> ocall( p, &Point::print, 5 );
  ocall.exec() ;

  CallbackPObject1<Point*, PointPrintFcnType, int> ocallP( &p, &Point::print, 2 );
  ocallP.exec() ;
```

It works reasonably ok, but its not as clean inside as I would like.